# How to display background image when url-pattern is wrong

Tags: css, jsf, error-handling, web.xml

web.xml mapping is

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

ErrorHandler servlet makes request

```
RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("error.jsp");
view.forward(request, response);
```

jsp error-page contains the style

```
body {
        background-image: url(err-images/fon.png);
    }
```

How to display background image in error-page when url-pattern is wrong, for example
`http://localhost:8080/WEBSearchPrime_JB/wrong/register.xhtml`

well, at leats one solution is to upload images to external hosting and using the absolute urls :)

Comment: @BalusC yes, that's it.

Answer (score -2):

Add a separate Page for the errors and configure the errors with their status port in web.xml file. like this

```
      <error-page>
      <error-code>400</error-code>
      <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/errorpages/ErrorPage400.jsp</location>
      </error-page>
```

Like for wrong URL it will throws error msg with status  port  404.

Comment: There is no problem with opening error pages for me. The project error page opens but the images is not displaed.

Comment: body {
        background-image: url(/err-images/fon.png);
    }                                                                                                                        or use this                                                                                                      <body background="err-images/fon.png">

Comment: also You can check is any other  css  file is included on  page                       try this also in the  html/jsp page itself in body tag                                         <body style=" background-image: url(err-images/fon.png)";>

Comment: no, all that I've allready done as you could see from the question

Comment: <html>
<body style="background-image: url(ima.jpg)";> 
</body>
</html> i have tried the same on myend and its working fine here.

Comment: have you tried it with `jsf` project where `Faces Servlet` mapped to `/faces/*`? and that error page should appears with wrong path mapping, for example `http://localhost:8080/appname/wrong/pagename.xhtml`

Comment: @BalusC i have that's why i suggested him to put the css explicitly in html tag only.if its a problem of jsf then the error page itself will not be rendered there. So defiantly its problem with  image path  or other css(may be included )  creating the problem .